# Spurious comma present

Tags: vba

I have a problem with one VBA script.

I got the message "spurious comma present". Do you know what this message means?

Comment: It means that you have a spurious comma in your code, maybe if you could elaborate a little we could help a bit more.  Add your code.

Comment: Is this an actual Excel generated error message?  Or is it a message that your own code displays when it detects a certain condition?  If the latter, look at the condition you use to decide whether to display the message - that will tell you what the message means.

Comment: "Spurious" in this case means "extra." There is an extra comma someplace in your code that the VBA system doesn't know what to do with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us the code that causes the error. I suggest you create a [mcve]. Then [edit] that into your question. With more information, maybe we can help.